# OpenCV CUDA Morphology is much slower than on CPU

Tags: c++, opencv

I am processing images of the dimension *2208x1242* from a video in a while-loop, using C++ with OpenCV.
To speed things up, I wanted to execute the operations on the GPU of my Nvidia Jetson Nano.
For the color conversion from BGR to HSV using `cv::cuda::cvtColor` instead of `cv::cvtColor` I achieve a speedup by factor 5.

Unfortunately, morphological operations are much slower on the GPU:

```
int num_frame = 10;
int frame = 0;

cv::Mat img;
cv::cuda::GpuMat img_gpu;

cv::Mat open_kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(11, 11));
cv::Mat close_kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(21, 21));

while (frame < num_frame){

  // load image to img
  // ...

  img_gpu.upload(img);

  cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::Filter> morph_filter_open = cv::cuda::createMorphologyFilter(cv::MORPH_OPEN, img_gpu.type(), open_kernel);
  cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::Filter> morph_filter_close = cv::cuda::createMorphologyFilter(cv::MORPH_CLOSE, img_gpu.type(), close_kernel);

  morph_filter_open->apply(img_gpu, img_gpu);
  morph_filter_close->apply(img_gpu, img_gpu);

  frame++;
}
```

Measuring only the `apply()`-calls, the GPU version is about 20x slower than `cv::morphologyEx` on the CPU of the Jetson Nano (**0.07s** vs. **1.5s** for a single frame).

`nvprof` shows, that most of the time is spent doing `cudaDeviceSynchronize` (this is for the whole program doing more things that the code sample above, but the long running operations are probably related to the morphology):

```
  API calls:   71.05%  17.2756s       665  25.978ms  25.730us  1.44814s  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                8.36%  2.03194s      1826  1.1128ms  34.844us  847.66ms  cudaLaunchKernel
                5.16%  1.25490s         1  1.25490s  1.25490s  1.25490s  cuCtxDestroy
                4.80%  1.16684s       544  2.1449ms  17.865us  10.378ms  cudaMallocPitch
                1.89%  460.14ms       616  746.98us  20.469us  346.82ms  cudaFree
                1.65%  401.38ms        76  5.2813ms  44.533us  19.211ms  cudaMemcpy2D
                1.45%  352.97ms        51  6.9209ms  18.803us  242.14ms  cudaMalloc
                1.42%  345.25ms         1  345.25ms  345.25ms  345.25ms  cudaFuncGetAttributes
                1.23%  299.95ms         1  299.95ms  299.95ms  299.95ms  cuCtxCreate
                1.03%  251.43ms        20  12.572ms  162.61us  103.74ms  cudaMallocManaged
                0.92%  224.67ms        13  17.283ms  32.553us  65.173ms  cudaMemcpy
                0.56%  135.48ms         1  135.48ms  135.48ms  135.48ms  cudaDeviceReset
...
```

I hope someone can help me figure out what the problem is!

Comment: I was going to post the same question since i got similar similar results in my evaluation results. I hope you got any update about what causes this!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I tested the exact same code using other, similar functions (cv::cuda::createGaussianFilter) and I found that it is a good bit faster than cv::GaussianBlur, so I suspect the issue to be in the implementation of cv::cuda::createMorphologyFilter itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I managed to improve the performance of CUDA based morphology by some margin. Instead of creating morphology filter objects in the loop, I took out the object creation and put it outside of the image capture loop.

So the code should look like this:

```
int num_frame = 10;
int frame = 0;

cv::Mat img;
cv::cuda::GpuMat img_gpu;

cv::Mat open_kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(11, 11));
cv::Mat close_kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, 

cv::Size(21, 21));

// Morphology filter object creation outside the loop.
cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::Filter> morph_filter_open = cv::cuda::createMorphologyFilter(cv::MORPH_OPEN, img_gpu.type(), open_kernel);
cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::Filter> morph_filter_close = cv::cuda::createMorphologyFilter(cv::MORPH_CLOSE, img_gpu.type(), close_kernel);

while (frame < num_frame){

  // load image to img
  // ...

  img_gpu.upload(img);

  morph_filter_open->apply(img_gpu, img_gpu);
  morph_filter_close->apply(img_gpu, img_gpu);

  frame++;
}
```

I couldn't find any way to improve the performance of the CUDA morphology filter beyond this.