# opencv - cuda python: Erode and Dilate are slower on GPU then CPU. Why?

Tags: python, opencv

I try to move my code from CPU to Cuda on Opencv-python (v 4.4.5) with a Quadro P1000.

I experienced a massive gain in speed for background subtraction, but morphological operations are slower than on CPU.

There are several related questions to this, but most of them are related to c++ or do not propose any useful ideas. ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526786/opencv-cuda-running-slower-than-opencv-cpu?rq=1), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61058327/opencv-cuda-morphology-is-much-slower-than-on-cpu), [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985337/why-my-opencv-cuda-is-running-slower-than-cpu-for-simple-thresholding?rq=1))

My code for testing returns that the CPU implementation for the morphological operator is at 20 fps, while the GPU implementation is at 10 FPS on 4k video stream.

```
import cv2
from vidgear.gears import VideoGear
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import time
#print(cv2.__file__)
cv2.cuda.setDevice(1)
cv2.cuda.printCudaDeviceInfo(1)



erosion_size = 3
erosion_shape = cv2.MORPH_RECT
element_erosion = cv2.getStructuringElement(erosion_shape, (2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1),
                                    (erosion_size, erosion_size))

dilatation_size = 3
dilation_shape = cv2.MORPH_RECT
element_dilation = cv2.getStructuringElement(dilation_shape, (2 * dilatation_size + 1, 2 * dilatation_size + 1),
                                    (dilatation_size, dilatation_size))

def morphological_filter(img):
    ## erosion and dilation are faster on cpu ? WTH
    erosion_dst = cv2.erode(img, element_erosion,iterations=1)
    dilatation_dst = cv2.dilate(erosion_dst, element_dilation, iterations=3)
    dilatation_dst = cv2.dilate(dilatation_dst, element_dilation)
    return dilatation_dst
path = "path/to/vid"
cap = VideoGear(source=path,backend = cv2.CAP_FFMPEG).start()
backSub = cv2.cuda.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

img_c = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
img = cap.read()
img_c.upload(img)
img_c = cv2.cuda.cvtColor(img_c, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
background =  cv2.cuda_GpuMat(img_c.size(),img_c.type())
print(img_c.size())


dilation_cuda = cv2.cuda.createMorphologyFilter(cv2.MORPH_DILATE, img_c.type(), element_dilation)
erosion_cuda = cv2.cuda.createMorphologyFilter(cv2.MORPH_ERODE, img_c.type(), element_erosion)


def morphological_filter_gpu(img):
    erosion_dst = erosion_cuda.apply(img)
    dilatation_dst = dilation_cuda.apply(erosion_dst)
    dilatation_dst = dilation_cuda.apply(dilatation_dst)
    return dilatation_dst
start = time()
for i in tqdm(range(1000)):

    img = cap.read()
    if type(img) ==None:
        break 
    img_c.upload(img)
    img_c = cv2.cuda.cvtColor(img_c, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_d = backSub.apply(img_c, -1, cv2.cuda_Stream.Null()) 
    res = img_d.download()
    res = morphological_filter(res)

    
end = time()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("time elapsed: ", end-start)
print("FPS ",1000/(end-start))


path = "path/to/vid"
cap = VideoGear(source=path,backend = cv2.CAP_FFMPEG).start()

start = time()
for i in tqdm(range(1000)):

    img = cap.read()
    if type(img) ==None:
        break 
    img_c.upload(img)
    img_c = cv2.cuda.cvtColor(img_c, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_d = backSub.apply(img_c, -1, cv2.cuda_Stream.Null())
    img_d = morphological_filter_gpu(img_d)
    res = img_d.download()
end = time()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("time elapsed: ", end-start)
print("FPS ",1000/(end-start))
```

Now the final question: Is it due to the cuda implementation in opencv or do I use something wrong and if so: how to accelerate it?

Comment: This question is about the performance of GPU accelerated code paths in OpenCV. It isn’t about CUDA programming and it isn’t about PyCUDA. Please don’t misuse tags

Comment: I expect erode and dilate to be memory bound on CPU with multiple threads. So using a GPU does not help because of the slow transfer. Keeping everything on the GPU can help though. Hidden synchronizations might also be expensive.

Comment: When you observe the code, you can see that I do the same transfer steps in both comparisons. So one point might be checking the synchronization but not the transfer. As I understood it, morphological filters should be possible to calculate in constant time on the GPU?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/296002574_Performance_Analysis_Of_Morphological_Operations_in_CPU_and_GPU_for_Accelerating_Digital_Image_Applications